# build table with react table with api

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

good morning colleagues, I was building a table with data that is brought from after consuming the api, the problem is that this data does not have the normal structure of a json.

The file that the server gives me is this:

```
{
  "Sensor_Id": "1",
  "Temperature": "35.27",
  "Humidity": "61.4"
}
```

As you can see, it does not have the brackets ([]), that is why it does not read the variables when building the table, here I consume the api:

```
export function Sensores(props) {
  const [sensores, setSensores] = useState([]);

  const fetchSensores = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/ijrios/prueba2/sensores")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    if (response) {
      const sensores = "["+response.data+"]";

      console.log("Sensores: ", sensores);
      setSensores(sensores);
    }

  };
```

and here I build the columns:

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: "Sensor_Id",
      },
      {
        Header: "Temperatura",
        accessor: "Temperature",
      },
      {
        Header: "Humedad",
        accessor: "Humidity",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const DatoSensores = useMemo(() => [...sensores], [sensores]);

  const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
      columns: columns,
      data: DatoSensores,
    }
  );
```

As the file that arrives is a json with a different structure, it does not write any data to the table, I need help to be able to read data and display it on the screen, thx u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const sensores = "["+response.data+"]";
```

This generates a **string** with `[` 's around `response.data`

---

React Tables needs a regular [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) as data source, so lets make one;

```js
const sensores = [ response.data ];
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I need practice!